# Do Androids' hairs grow?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

In the Alien movies, I have never recalled seeing an Android's hair growing longer. But in *Alien: Covenant* (2017), David was cutting his hair.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Alien movies are set over a number of days, whereas the time difference between *Prometheus* and *Alien: Covenant* is years. The fact that David has to cut his hair is proof alone that yes, David's hair does grow over time.

It's probably worth noting that this doesn't mean that all androids have hair that grows. It is specifically pointed out in *Alien: Covenant* that Walter and David, while seemingly identical on the surface, are actually very different models of android, with Walter having been "downgraded" in some areas to make people more comfortable around him. For all we know, hair growth is something that was stripped from the later models of android.

Comment: I haven't seen _Aliens: Covenant_ yet. But I in _Aliens_, Bishop says he prefers the term "artificial human", and we clearly see that he has slimy yellow innards instead of circuits and gears. It could be that he "grows" (as does his hair).

Comment: The Prometheus DVD showed that Walters creator preferred machines over their competitors bioengineering. They are robots, mechanical, unlike blade runner replicants.